#  Simple: Sending data from UI results in different string on the server?

Tags: java, apache-flex, character-encoding

I am trying to import xsd files from the client browser to the server and then process them on the server.

My client code is in Adobe Flex. My server code is in java.

The design is something like this:

Client composes upload request with the filename (In Flex) (I validated that the file name reflected here is the one that is correct in all encoding.)
                    |
                    |
                    V
Server receives the request and starts to process the file. The files name seen here is the same as seen in the UI if the encoding is ASCII but if the client sent out something like (カルディスク.xsd) then at the server I see the string as (ã‚«ãƒ«ãƒ‡ã‚£ã‚¹ã‚¯.xsd)

I do understand that in flex data type string, the default is UTF-16.

Is there any way I can decode the string received at the server? I am assuming here that there is an encoding problem. I do not understand what encoding is this ã‚«ãƒ«ãƒ‡ã‚£ã‚¹ã‚¯?

If someone can tell me the 2 encoding used then I can make sure that the server always decodes it before processing.

I appreciate your time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can easily decode the string properly on the server if you use the java CharSet encodings.  There are several encodings supported, by default, in the JDK documentation.  When the string comes in, you will have to decode it as necessary

Comment: Do you mean use charset to store the file name on the server instead of a string? And also could you also tell me exactly how should I be doing this?